# Can I roll over 401k without leaving job, into personal IRA

Tags: 401k, solo-401k

I am younger than 40.  Can I move my current employer-sponsored 401k funds to a personal IRA, without penality, and without leaving the company?

Comment: According to https://money.stackexchange.com/q/2660/71269 (possible duplicate), it is not possible except in very specific circumstances.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I roll over a 401(k) with my current employer into an IRA?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/2660/can-i-roll-over-a-401k-with-my-current-employer-into-an-ira) Check your plan details, but looks like in general in-service rollover is limited to those age 59.5 and up.